# MS Access form groups records after splitting database

Tags: ms-access

After successfully splitting my Access database I have noticed an odd behavior in the primary user form. When I enter a new record in a subform, it moves places after navigating away from and back to an order. Here is an image of the form before navigating away from an order. You can see "TEST ENTRY" is the last record in the subform.
[image: Before save]

Here is a picture from after navigating away from and back to the order. You can see that "TEST ENTRY" record has moved to the first row, above items entered earlier. Its almost as if the subform is sorting on some criteria I'm unaware of now.
[image: After Save]

All the data looks good when I view the tables themselves, but I find this a bit odd, as it never happened before splitting the database.

I would appreciate any advice the community has to offer. Much thanks.

Comment: Is the back end still an Access back-end - not SQL server or something else ?

Comment: @Minty it’s an Access backend. I ended up abandoning the split database approach as it caused issues for some users, but I appreciate any thoughts you may have.

Comment: You should resolve that problem and stick with the split setup - it is the _only_ way in the long run.